# Enter an operator to perform a math operation

Tags: python

I want to enter an operator, +, -, *, /, //, %, to perform a math operation using this program in python. How do I code these strings: "s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i)" for the .txt file funtions and "print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i)" to include the operator I choose? I'm not sure how to get this to work. Thanks for your time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter Number of .txt Files to Create:")) # number of txt files
   
    for x in range(0, n):
        n=int(input("Enter a Number to Create Multiples of: "))
        import operator
        operatorlookup = {
            '+': operator.add,
            '-': operator.sub,
            '*': operator.mul,
            '/': operator.truediv}
        o=int(input("Enter Calculation Symbols for Calculation You Want to Perform: "))
        m=operatorlookup.get(o)
        start=int(input("Enter a Start Range Number: "))
        end=int(input("Enter an End Range Number: "))
        f=int(input("Enter Table Number to Name .txt File: "))
        f_path = "table_" + str(f) + ".txt" # this will numerate each table 
        file = open(f_path, 'a') # 'a' tag will create a file if it doesn't exist
        
        if start<end:
            for i in range(start,end+1):
                s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i) # I want to put the math operation of my choosing here in this "str(n * i)".
                file.write(s)
                file.write("\n")
                print(n,"*",i,"=", n * i) # I want to put the math operation of my choosing here in this "n * i)".

        elif start>end:
            for i in range(start,end,-1):
                s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i) # I want to put the math operation of my choosing here in this "str(n * i)".
                file.write(s)
                file.write("\n")
                print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i) # I want to put the math operation of my choosing here in this "n * i)".

    file.close()
    print("\nYou are done creating files now. Run the program again if you want to create more. Thank you for using this program and have a nice day!\n")

w = tablep()
```

Comment: You can try using `exec()`

Comment: `exec()` isn't safe

Comment: @AminGuermazi well I guess it is because of what can be entered but if that is the case You can filter input

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
First, minimize this code; a majority of your post is unrelated to your question.

Comment: Second, show us exactly how your present solution doesn't work.
Don't expect us to enter test data for you; replace your input code with a hard-coded test case that shows your problem.  Also, do not expect us to reverse-engineer your algorithm from meaningless variable names.

Comment: You posted three different errors from one piece of code. This is very confusing. Can you please focus your question on one specific problem and post a [mre] of the code and error you have

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I removed the errors so there would be less confusion and they don't match up to the solution I gave. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary lookup:

```py
def evaluate(a: int, b: int, operation: str):
    oper = {
        "+": a+b, "-": a-b, "*": a*b, "/": a/b, "%": a%b, "//": a//b
    }
    return oper.get(operation)
```

With a few test runs:

```py
>>> evaluate(2, 5, "+")
7
>>> evaluate(2, 5, "-")
-3
>>> evaluate(2, 5, "*")
10
>>> evaluate(2, 5, "bananas")
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
operator = input('Enter an operator: ')

operators = '+-**/'

if operator in operators:
    executable = f'print(2{operator}3)'
    exec(executable)
```

The program will ask for user input and then check if the input is in operators and if it is it will print out whatever result from using 2 and 3 and that operator. You can put pretty much any code in that `f string`.

About security:

As someone in the comments mentioned this isn't safe (the use of `exec()`)? Since I can only assume it is because then it is possible to run any code (including malicious) You can just filter what the user inputs.

Here is probably an implementation to Your code (should use python 3.6 or higher or sth like that that supports `f strings`):

```py
n = 5
i = 3
operator = '*'

# main part ========================
result = None
exec(f"""result = {n}{operator}{i}""", globals())

s = f'''{n} * {i} = {result}'''
print(s)
```

However this doesn't seem as efficient as I thought at first so You probably are better of using the other answer with using dictionaries and defining a function.

Comment: According to learnpython.org, Mixing operators between numbers and strings is not supported. Here is the link: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types. How would I get the operator I enter to calculate the math of the multiplication tables or whichever operator I choose?

Comment: did You even try out the sample code? there is no actual mixing between numbers and strings when executing the code. Do You even understand what my example accomplishes? it uses an operator the user has inputed to do something with integers 2 and 3 be it dividing, multiplication, subtractions, addition, raising to the power. That is at leas what I understood from You: You want to be able to input an operator (mathematical like + - / *) and use it to perform mathematical stuff. for example instead of two and three there was data from Your table and You let user choose what operator to use.

Comment: *"You can just filter what the user inputs"*. If this is part of your solution, you would have to provide how you would do it.

Comment: @JacobLee actually I did in my code show how to do that. The code checks if the operator is in the `operators` string. `if operator in operators:`

Comment: Yes, I did try the sample code and I don't know how to implement it for the "print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i)" functions and the "s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i)" functions. I also tried your sample code by itself using python2 and it doesn't work. The sample code works by itself with python3, and I have no idea how to combine this function: executable = "f'print(2{operator}3)'" with my functions "print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i)" functions and the "s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i)". I tried replacing the * in this: str(n * i) with str(n {*} i). That didn't work, so how?

Comment: That string is going to get converted into python code, so basically You can ignore those first '' around the whole thing for inderstanding purposes. Also I will try understand Your code better and see if I can think of something

Comment: @ubuntuuser771 I made an edit to my answer and added a sample implementation tho it seems much easier to just use what the other answer suggested: dictionaries

Comment: @Matiiss, your answer inspired my idea to do what I did in my answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work, I took the code I had: "s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n * i)" and modified this line using inspiration from code provided by @Matiiss: "exec(f"""result = {n}{operator}{i}""", globals())". My new line is this: "str(n) + str(operator) + str(i) + "= " + str(n + i)". I then made 4 lines with it. Each line does one math operation: +, -, *, /. Then I did a nested if statement for each individual operation under the four lines that calls on the dictionary that @JacobLee provided. Combined with the user input code for choosing an operator, the operator the user chooses will call on the corresponding nested if statement. Finally, the code inside the nested if statement will perform the math and write it to the .txt file. Thanks for your answers everyone, they helped a lot. Have a nice day.